# Ayuda con el algoritmo A star (A*)

Tags: r

tengo los siguientes algoritmos en R de busqueda sin Información, pero no he sido capaz de implementar el algoritmoa A star (A*), dejo mi código de los algoritmos implementados.

He intentado realizarlo, pero no encuentro la manera ya que no entiendo muy bien lo del costo que se maneja, los algoritmos estan implementados en el lenguaje R, es decir que este nuevo algoritmo tambien debe de estar en el mismo lenguaje.

Les pido una colaboración, es de gran ayuda cualquier dato que me puedan proporcionar.

Muchas gracias.

```
#----------------------funcion encarga de realizar la busqueda en profundidad Limitada
profundidadLimitada= function(nodoini){
    nodo=nodoini;
    frontera=vector(mode='list');
    frontera[[1]]=nodo;
    visitados=list();
    pendientes=c(1);
    cond=0;
    n=0;


    while (cond==0){

        n=n+1;
        print(n);

        nodo= frontera[[length(frontera)]];
        frontera=frontera[-length(frontera)];
        pendientes[length(pendientes)]=pendientes[length(pendientes)]-1;
        visitados=c(visitados,list(nodo));
        vecinos=puzzle.states(nodo);

            if(length(visitados)== 10){
                hijos=c();
            }else{
                hijos=setdiff(vecinos,c(visitados,frontera));

            }

            pendientes=c(pendientes,length(hijos));

            if(length(hijos)>0){
                for(i in 1:length(hijos)){

                  if(finalizar(hijos[[i]])){
                        cond=1;
                        return(hijos[i]);

                    break; 
                    }

              }
            }



            if(any(pendientes!=0)){
                if(pendientes[length(pendientes)]==0){
                    while(pendientes[length(pendientes)]==0){
                        visitados=visitados[-length(visitados)]
                        pendientes=pendientes[-length(pendientes)]
                    }

                }else{
                    frontera=c(frontera,hijos); 
                }

            }else{
                cond=2
            }
       }

}

#----------------------funcion encarga de realizar la busqueda en anchura2
anchura2= function(nodoini){
    nodo=nodoini;
    frontera=vector(mode='list');
    frontera[[1]]=nodo;
    visitados=list();
    padres=list(NA);
    cond=0;
    n=0;

    while (cond==0){

        nodo= frontera[[1]];
        visitados=c(visitados,list(nodo));
        frontera=frontera[-1];
        vecinos=puzzle.states(nodo);
        hijos=setdiff(vecinos,c(visitados,frontera));
        padres=c(padres,rep(list(nodo),length(hijos)));

        if(length(hijos)>0){
            for(i in 1:length(hijos)){
                if(finalizar(hijos[[i]])){
                    cond=1;
                    visitados=c(visitados,frontera);
                    visitados=c(visitados,list(hijos[[i]]));
                    return(list(visitados, padres));
                    break; 
                }

            }
        }

        n=n+1
        print(n)
        frontera=c(frontera,hijos);


        print(length(frontera));
        print(length(visitados));
    }

}
```

Comment: El algoritmo A* ya tiene algunas implementaciones en R. El paquete `cpprouting` ya lo contempla y sino tienes esto: https://github.com/machow/astar-r. Ahora, si se trata de una tarea académica, te sugiero que compartas el código de lo que hayas intentado y que dificultades has tenido, para que la pregunta sea bien recibida. Saludos.